cannot find the scrollbar in variables reivews in vscode
I cannot find the scrollbar in my variables review in vscode recently? Before it had, and I do not know what happend.  Does anyone know how to get it back? Thanks!
I checked the settings and seems everythings is fine. Not sure if I miss something.

most likely hidden. Set the scroll bar to auto as shown on the attached image
